How can i switch multiple chrome profiles by their names in DrissionPage ChromiumPage?
My current code doesn't switch from one profile to other
from DrissionPage import ChromiumOptions, ChromiumPage,Chromium
co = ChromiumOptions()
co.set_user(user='event_name1')
page = ChromiumPage(co)
co = ChromiumOptions()
co.set_user(user='event_name2')
page = ChromiumPage(co)


You would need to give the actual name of profile, what i mean is suppose you created a profile in chrome (Profile 2). Now if you try to switch to this profile using this co.set_user("Profile 2"), drission wont switch to this profile because under the hood it is looking for a unique identifier of this profile, if it cant find then drission will create a new profile. But if you want to switch back to default profile which is named as Profile  1. Then you would have to switch like this co.set_user("Default"). Then only drission will know ok i have to switch to Profile 1.

@Aniket Thanks for your answer, I tried this thing multiple times but it does not work. The issue is that Chromium targets a port for opening a browser  and if we do not provide a port to it then it will open the browser at its default  port so if we have to open multiple instances at a time  then for each instance we have to provide different port name or call a auto port for various number of instances

I understand but your question was how can you switch multiple chrome profiles by their names!! So i tried to help you based on that only but nevertheless it worked so its fine!!

from DrissionPage import Chromium
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

# Dictionary of event links
event_links = {
    '1': 'http://drissionpage.cn/browser_control/mode_change/',
    '2': 'https://DrissionPage.cn',
    '3': 'https://example.com'
}

# Predefined Chromium instances with specific debugging ports
browsers = {
    '1': Chromium(9222),  # Browser 1 on port 9222
    '2': Chromium(9333),  # Browser 2 on port 9333
    '3': Chromium(9444)   # Browser 3 on port 9444
}

# Function to open a URL in a specific browser instance
def open_browser(args):
    session_id, url = args  # Unpack session ID and URL

    # Retrieve the associated browser instance
    browser = browsers[session_id]
    tab = browser.latest_tab  
    # Navigate the browser to the target URL
    tab.get(url)
    print(f"Browser session {session_id} opened for URL: {url}")
    
    return session_id, url

# Main function to manage concurrent browser sessions
def main():
    # Use ThreadPoolExecutor for concurrent execution
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(event_links)) as executor:
        # Submit tasks for each session (key, URL pair)
        futures = {executor.submit(open_browser, (key, url)): (key, url) for key, url in event_links.items()}
        
        # Process results as they are completed
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            try:
                session_id, url = future.result()  # Retrieve session ID and URL
                print(f"Session {session_id} completed for URL: {url}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in session: {e}")

# Run the script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

